# Is there a way to slow down a gif as a background in html and css?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website for school. As a background of the first page I chose a gif. But the gif is too fast. Is there some attribute or a way to slow down the gif. Maybe there is something I can type in css to slow it down?

Comment: No, CSS and HTML have no way to alter the speed of an animated gif

Answer (score 8):

You need to resample the gif to change the speed of it.

I haven't tried this tool, but perhaps it will be of help to you: http://ezgif.com/speed

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, there is no way to directly control the animation of a GIF with only HTML/CSS.

However, the answer to your other question is "yes" - there *are* ways to slow down your GIF, or even enable complete CSS control of the animation, with a little help from an image editor.

If you're willing to use an image editor, such as the excellent and free **[GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/)**, then **there are some simple solutions to this problem**. No experience necessary.

---

### The Simple Problem/Solution

When you really just need to change the GIF speed and *don't really need to control it with CSS*.

1. Open your GIF file with GIMP.
2. In the "Layers" panel, change the layer display duration to whatever you need for each layer. It is displayed like this: `(40ms)`. Just double click the name and enter your new time (80ms if you want to slow it down to half speed in this example), then press enter.
3. Export as a GIF!

---

### The Complex Problem/Solution

When you *do need* dynamic control of the animation using CSS.

**Overview:** We'll convert the GIF into a PNG spritemap, make it the background-image of our HTML element, then use a basic CSS animation to move the frames in steps. With this we gain full control over animation easing, duration, and delay. The code below shows a basic example of the result, followed by a detailed breakdown.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="slowme"></div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.slowme {
  background: url("url-for-spritemap.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: 2400%;
  animation: anim-ss steps(23) 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes anim-ss { 0% {background-position: 0%;} 100% {background-position: 100%;} }
```

#### Detailed Explanation

1. **Convert the GIF into a spritemap**. You can do this completely manually, though it is tedious if the GIF has many layers. (See manual and automatic spritemap solutions at the bottom for detailed instructions.)
2. Set the spritemap as the background image of a div.
3. Set the background-size attribute to be a 100% multiplied by your number of frames. In this example, I have 24 frames, so background-size is 2400%. This changes the size of the image relative to the width of your div so that each "frame" of the spritemap is the width to fill the div.
4. Add a basic keyframes animation to your CSS (code below) to control the position over time. This will move the background image from right to left over the course of the animation.
5. Set the animation for the div including the `steps()` for the animation-timing-function property. Set the steps to be the number of frames *minus 1*. Since we have 24 frames in this example, we'll use `steps(23)`. Without the steps, the image background would slide smoothly, the steps move the background in step with frame widths.
6. That's it!

The animation should look exactly like the GIF did, except now you can control it like a standard CSS animations.

**Control Examples**

```css
/* Slow the animation (by increasing duration) to half */
animation: anim-ss steps(23) 2s infinite;

/* Delay the animation start by 5 seconds */
animation: anim-ss steps(23) 1s 5s infinite;

/* Pause the animation (can use to pause/play with a JS button) */
animation-play-state: paused;

/* Play animation in reverse */
animation: anim-ss steps(23) 1s 5s infinite reverse;
```

I know this was a lot of extra information, but I really hope it helps someone out there!

---

### Detailed GIMP Instructions

**Please Note:** These instructions are correct at time of writing, using GIMP v2.10. If they fail you, future reader, please refer to the [GIMP documentation](https://www.gimp.org/docs/).

#### Manual Spritemap Conversion

1. Increase the canvas width to make room for all frames. So if the GIF is 219x219px, and there are 10 layers (frames) then change the canvas width to 2190px.

   - `Image > Canvas Size`
2. Set your grid to allow for easy snapping.

   - `View > Show Grid`
   - `View > Snap to Grid`
   - `Image > Configure Grid`

     - Set the horizontal and vertical spacing to your frame dimensions.
3. On each layer, move the contents to the respective grid position. So the base frame image is in the leftmost slot, then frame 2 (in the 2nd layer) is directly to the right, and so on.

   - Click on the layer of the frame you're moving in the Layers panel to select it.
   - Select the "Move Tool" by pressing `M`.
   - Select the contents of the layer with `ctrl/cmd-a` then drag them to the correct grid position.
4. Export as a PNG: `File > Export As` , then change the file extension to PNG and export.

#### Automatic Spritemap Conversion

A simple [GIMP plugin created by Spydarlee](https://github.com/Spydarlee/scripts/blob/master/GIMP/create_spritesheet.py) will automate the whole process for you.

1. Download that file (or create a `script.py` file yourself and paste the code into it).
2. Paste/move the script into your plugins folder.

   - To find the plugins folder location in GIMP: `Edit > Preferences > Folders > Plug-ins`
3. Restart GIMP to load the plugin.
4. Open the GIF in GIMP.
5. Use the plugin:  `Filters > Animation > Create Spritesheet`
6. Change "Output to a single row?" to "Yes" and then click "Ok". All Done!

Comment: simplest: open gimp & export to gif and overwrite settings in export dialog

Answer (score 1):

No.. Never. Because the gif is an image type. You can consider it as a set of image that rapodally change. The movement is not made by the CSS animation so can not control if using CSS. Find another image or make own CSS animation.