# Best way to animate object/image randomly around within a div?

Tags: reactjs, animation

I have an animated gif, which I want to animate slowly and smoothly around. The gif needs to stay with the parent div. Which reactJS libraries would you suggest using for this task? As I guess it cannot be done only using CSS.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/68231607/1065780

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the reply. I'm not trying to control the actual gif frame rate, but simply make the div holding the gif animation move slowly, at random around the screen.

Comment: It seems like your question is not about the gif. Do you want to figure out how to move a `div` around the screen similar to the TV screensavers when a logo is floating around and bounces of edges, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to take a look at tutorials like this one:
https://css-tricks.com/bounce-element-around-viewport-in-css/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

img, div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.x {
  animation: x 2.6s linear infinite alternate;
}

.y {
  animation: y 0.8s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes x {
  100% {
    transform: translateX( calc(100vw - 100px) );
  }
}

@keyframes y {
  100% {
    transform: translateY( calc(100vh - 100px) );
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
  <img class="y" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg/768px-Stack_Overflow_icon.svg.png" alt="codepen" />
</div>
```